# Scala: Spec2 Dependencies

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, spec2

how would one declare dependencies in Spec2 (Unit-Style)?

Example:

```
object MySpec extends Specification {
  firstDo MyOtherSpec
}
```

So MyOtherSpec's test execute before MySpec's tests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, that might not be a good idea. The purpose of Unit tests is that they test small, encapsulated units. The need to run them sequentially is not only a waste of resources (parallel computation), but also points to potential problems in encapsulation.

Nevertheless, inside a specification you can put intermediate steps to be completed. Execution will be in parallel for all definition before a step, then for all after, but steps are completed in order. Check [this](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Steps%2FActions) and [this](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.4/index.html#org.specs2.specification.Step) for relevant documentation.